# Show just the name of collection?

Tags: laravel, api

I have pivot table `post_tag` between posts and tags table.

I want to show the tags name for each post in resource API.

Resource file code snippets:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'Name'=> $this->title,
        'Description'=> $this->desc,
        'Image'=> $this->image_path,
        'Posted By'=> $this->user->name,
        'Category Name'=> $this->category->name,
        'Tags' => $this->tags,
    ];
}
```

Relation added in Post model:

```
public function tags()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class)->withTimestamps();
}
```

One of Results of an API:

```
 "Name": "first post",
    "Description": "desc of the post",
    "Image": "https://blog.test/uploads/post/SjvDfC1Zk5UzGO6ViRbjUQTMocwCh0lzEYW1Gufp.jpeg",
    "Posted By": "test",
    "Category Name": "web dev",
    "Tags": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "HTML",
            "created_at": "2020-01-08 19:19:55",
            "updated_at": "2020-01-08 19:19:55",
            "pivot": {
                "post_id": 1,
                "tag_id": 1,
                "created_at": "2020-01-08 19:21:40",
                "updated_at": "2020-01-08 19:21:40"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "CSS",
            "created_at": "2020-01-08 19:19:55",
            "updated_at": "2020-01-08 19:19:55",
            "pivot": {
                "post_id": 1,
                "tag_id": 2,
                "created_at": "2020-01-08 19:21:40",
                "updated_at": "2020-01-08 19:21:40"
            }
        },
```

I need to show like that JUST names:

```
"Tags" : {
    'HTML',
    'CSS',
    'JS',
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must be use like this

```
return [
    'Name'=> $this->title,
    'Description'=> $this->desc,
    'Image'=> $this->image_path,
    'Posted By'=> $this->user->name,
    'Category Name'=> $this->category->name,
    'Tags' => $this->tags->pluck('name')
];
```

Comment: worked perfectly! but why when I write like this not working ( $this->tags>name ) ?

Comment: because $this->tags is instance of Collection

Comment: and last thing ( is my image correct like this ?) means for mobile app is this best practice for image to put the url ?

Comment: I am not sure that is best way but I also use image url like you. Other case you canse use base_64

Comment: https://github.com/codeareaam/laraarea-transformer. This is my made package. I will write docs soon

Comment: Cool! about what this package?